# Reading client response crashes server

Tags: c, linux, server, signals, posix

I am writing a program where a server is signaled to by another program, upon receiving the signal it reads a directory name from a shared memory segment and sends this to a client through a sock. The client sends back the contents of the directory and disconnects

My problem is that when the server receives the client response, it prints it and immediately stops listening on the port.

The program works in all other instances, such as the client connecting, not sending anything, then disconnecting.

```
void handler(int signal_number)
{   
    int read_size;
    char* cli_dir[1000];
    char *message , client_message[2000];
    int i = 0;

    printf("about to access shared memory");
    message = shm; //shm is the directory name in shared memory
    puts("accessed shared memory");
    printf("is gonna be sent to client %s\n",message);
    write(sock , (char*)message , strlen(message));

    while((read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //read client response and log contents of the received directory
        printf("\n%s\n", (char*)client_message);
        strcpy(cli_dir[i],(char*)client_message);
        i++;
        printf("\n");
        perror("error here");
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
        perror("error 2 here"); 
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("receiving server side failed");
    }
}

void* connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    printf("accessed connection handler");

    sock = *(int*)socket_desc;

    while(1){

        signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

        // struct sigaction sa;
        // printf("signal recieved");
        // memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa)); //alternative signal handler
        // sa.sa_handler = &handler;
        // sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

        pause();
    }
}
```

Also, here is how I am accepting connections in the main function

```
    while( (client_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Client accepted");

        pthread_t sniff;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        pthread_join( sniff , NULL);
        puts("client handled");
    }

    if (client_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: You should post enough code that someone can compile ... as it stands it's not really "testable" by anyone

Comment: 'printf("\n%s\n", (char*)client_message);' requies a NUL-terminated char aray, something that is not giaranteed by your code.

Comment: ...and 'strcpy(cli_dir[i],(char*)client_message);'

Comment: 'pthread_join( sniff , NULL);' called on unitialized var.

Comment: 'pthread_join( sniff , NULL);' even if it worked, is not required and blocks the accept loop.

Comment: What is the signal handler for, and why is it making so many signal-unsafe calls?

Comment: I'm not sure how what your overall requirement is, but your design is borked.

Comment: The signal handler is for when the main program signals to the server that it is ok to read from shared memory. Sorry if the code looks amateur, its because I am teaching myself C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as Martin James already said,

```
printf("\n%s\n", (char*)client_message);
```

requires a NUL-terminated string. This is not forced by your server code and if you send a NUL-terminated string from a client like

```
write(fd, str, strlen(str));
```

then you will not send a `'\0'` (you need to send `strlen(str) + 1` bytes or add `'\0'` at the receiving end being careful to not overflow your buffer by 1 byte).

Second, I'm not familiar with writing signal-safe/unsafe code, so cannot comment on this, but here may be problems too.

## Main problem

IMHO the main problem with your code is that you declare an uninitialized array `cli_dir` of pointers to strings and then pass such pointer to `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(cli_dir[i],(char*)client_message);
```

If I get your code right, here you pass a pointer to a memory location, to which `strcpy` have to copy a string, but you did not allocated somehow a memory for a copy and `cli_dir[i]` contains now some arbitrary garbage. This most probably will result in a Segmentation fault.